# Can I configure git for easier cloning from GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I would like to be able to clone a repo from GitHub with something like `git clone user/repo` instead of typing out the whole url. Is it possible to configure this in git, or should I just make a separate command for it?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking? You're asking for a `git clone [url]` command that is somehow shorter than `git clone [url]`?

Comment: @ObsidianAge I'm asking if there some way to have git clone from a gh url without needing the whole url, via it's configurations.

Comment: @ObsidianAge OP wants to avoid typing the `https://github.com/` in the URL

Comment: @wjandrea and the `.git` at the end ;)

Comment: @Mason You don't need the `.git` at the end :)

Comment: Mason, normally you don't type out the whole URL. It's copy-and-paste. See https://help.github.com/en/articles/cloning-a-repository

Answer (score 4):

Maybe what you are looking for is [hub](https://github.com/github/hub/blob/master/README.md)

> ### Usage
>
> ```sh
> $ hub clone rtomayko/tilt
>
> # expands to:
> $ git clone git://github.com/rtomayko/tilt.git
> ```
>
> hub can be safely aliased as `git` so you can type `$ git <command>` in the shell and get all the usual `hub` features.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind typing a few more characters,

```
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf g://
git clone g://user/repo
```

`g://` is just a fake protocol and will be replaced by `https://github.com/`. `g://` stands for `github` here and the `g` part can be named other words.

For a specific user, `tom` for example, you can even use,

```
git config --global url."https://github.com/tom/".insteadOf t://
git clone t://repo
```

`t://repo` will be replaced by `https://github.com/tom/repo`.

Answer (score 2):

You could set up a git alias like this:

```
clone-github = "!f(){ repo=$1; shift; git clone \"https://github.com/$repo\" \"$@\"; }; f"
```

Then use it like `git clone-github user/repo` For example:

```
$ git clone-github octocat/Spoon-Knife
Cloning into 'Spoon-Knife'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 16, done.
remote: Total 16 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 16
Unpacking objects: 100% (16/16), done.
```

Comment: What language is that function written in?

Comment: @Mason in `sh`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SSH’s shortcuts. Put the following in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host gh
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  Protocol 2
```

Now you can use the following:

```
git clone gh:user/repo

# equivalent to:
git clone git@github.com:user/repo
```

The great thing with this solution is that you can use it for other providers as well:

```
Host gl
  Hostname gitlab.mycompany.com
  User git
  Protocol 2
```

Then:

```
git clone gl:user/repo

# equivalent to:
git clone git@gitlab.mycompany.com:user/repo
```